# iOS Firebase Crash Reporting Crashes on Set Up

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have gone through several SO posts and followed the Firebase tutorial and I just don't seem to have any luck setting up the Crashes.

I added the Pod, and got to these steps

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

The second part is confusing to me, because the part that says FirebaseCrash/upload-sym...the upload-sym isn't a folder but a file...and therefore how can I continue down the hierarchy?

So I removed that part and I put the file which downloads as 'unknown' and I renamed it ServiceAccount.json and put it in the folder FirebaseCrash...and so that last line for me looks like

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/"ServiceAccount.json"
```

When I clean and build I get 1 error.

The error is very long but from what I can take from it is

```
....line 6: ...... /Pods/FirebaseCrash/ServiceAccount.json: Permission
denied
```

I have read in some SO posts that I need to go to a page called **permissions** and do something there.

I would like it if somebody can clearly say if what I have done so far is correct and if it is layout what I need to do because many of the posts are conflicting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirstI installed `pod 'Firebase/Crash'`,
Then i generated a key lets name it like you ServiceAccount.json
Created a folder within the App lets say MyApp and within MyApp where MyApp.xcodeproj and MyApp.xcworkspace are, there i created CrashReportingKey folder and added the ServiceAccount.json there.
Created a run script and it all was setup.
Added this on the script:

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:xxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxx

"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/CrashReportingKey/ServiceAccount.json
```

Comment: I have mine exactly like you have it there (with the exception of the xxxxx part where it is filled in) and I now get a new error ...now I get   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Comment: I also cleaned the project, held down option while cleaning, and deleted derived data...and I still get this exit code 2.....I noticed that the documentation says rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*.   but....when I run that in terminal it says "no matches found"

Comment: well, I tried adding " before and after the ${SRCROOT} and now it builds without error, now I will try to continue the set up, hopefully this was it!

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that this integration step is telling xcode to run the `upload-sym` script to upload the symbols.  You have to run that script - you can't remove it.  It receives an argument, which is the json file of the service account that gives permission to do the upload.

Comment: So then after the -sym...do I start the path over? Like say AppName/some folder/ the file?

Comment: It's safest to give the full path to the service account file as the argument to the upload-sym script.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using old code this is the new way

1- the first thing i did
is to update the podfile from pod 'Firebase/Crash' to
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

2 update the debug symbol[open here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgILr.png)

add the code run crashlytics
[open here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2bc0.png)